# concatenation items as result of one function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this function

```
def one():
    item1 = "one"
    item2 = "two"
    result = item1, item2
    return  result

print(one())
```

the output of this funciotn is in format tuple, like this

```
('one', 'two')
```

What can I do if I need the output not in tuple, so in the following format

```
one, two
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: replace `result = item1, item2` with `result = item1 + ', ' +  item2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
print(', '.join(one()))
```

Or in Python 3 you can simply use `print()` like this:

```
print(*one(), sep=', ')
```

which also works in Python 2 if you import `print_function` like this at the top of your file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: How can I call it in a nother funtion?

Comment: for example: for v, vv in *one(), sep=', ':

Comment: @gho: If you want a string then use `str.join()` as shown, and then pass that to the second function. e.g. `function2(', '.join(one()))`.Otherwise simply iterate over the returned tuple: `for item in one(): print(item)`.

Comment: I will not make print, I only use it as input for another function

Comment: @gho: did you read the answer and comments? Use `str.join()`, e.g. `another_function(', '.join(one()))`

Comment: When I call this: for v, vv in ', '.join(one(item)):  print(vv), I get this error: TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, set found

Comment: @gho: why are you doing that? Your function `one()` returns a tuple. You  can unpack the tuple into separate variables, if that's what you are hoping to do: `item1, item2 = one()` will set `item1` to the string `one`, and `item2` to `two`.

Comment: With my function I get this error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @gho: then the function that you posted in your question is different from the one that you are testing with.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack it and specify a custom separator:

```
print(*one(), sep=', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
def one():
    item1 = "one"
    item2 = "two"
    result = item1 + ", " + item2
    return  result

print(one())
```